# Step-up authentication with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm looking for guidance and/or best practices in implementing step-up authentication. The generic scenario is as follows: user logs in to web app using some identity provider, user then goes to some specific area of web site which needs to be protected by additional MFA, for example OTP. All functionality for the website is via REST API, authenticating with JWT bearer token.

The best description of the flow I found is from Auth0 [here](https://auth0.com/docs/login/mfa/step-up-authentication/configure-step-up-authentication-for-web-apps). Basically, user acquires the access token with scope which is just enough to access APIs that do not require additional protection. When there is a need to access secure API the authorization handler on backend would check if the token has the scope indicating that the user has completed the additional MFA check, otherwise it's just `HTTP 401`.

Some sources, including the one from Auth0, suggest using `amr` claim as an indication of passed MFA check. That means that identity provider must be able to return this claim in response to access token request with `acr_values` parameter.

Now, the detail that is bugging me: should the frontend know in advance the list of API that might require MFA and request the elevated permissions beforehand, or should frontend treat the `HTTP 401` response from backend as a signal to request elevated permissions and try again?

Should identity provider generate relatively additional short-lived token to access restricted APIs? Then, if frontend has 2 tokens it must definitely know which token to use with which API endpoint. Or maybe identity provider can re-issue the access token with normal lifespan but elevated permissions? Sounds less secure than the first approach.

Finally, do I understand the whole process right or not? Is there some well documented and time-tested flow at all?

Answer (score 0):

**CLIENTS**

Clients can be made aware of authentication strength via ID tokens. Note that a client should never read access tokens - ideally they should use an opaque / reference token format. Most commonly the `acr` claim from the ID token is used.

This can be a little ugly and a better option can sometimes be to ask the API, eg 'can I make a payment'? The client sends an access token and gets a JSON response tailored to what the UI needs. The API's job is to serve the client after all.

**APIs**

APIs receive JWT access tokens containing scopes and claims. Often this occurs after an API gateway [swaps an opaque token for a JWT](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/).

The usual technique is that some logic in the Authorization Server omits high privilege ones, eg a payment scope or claim, unless strong authentication was used.

It is worth mentioning plain old API error responses here. Requests with an insufficient scope typically return 403, though a useful JSON error code in an error object can be useful for giving the client a more precise reason.

**STEP UP**

As you indicate, this involves the client running a new code flow, with different scope / claims and potentially also with an `acr_values` parameter. The [Curity MFA Approaches](https://curity.io/resources/learn/approaches-to-mfa/) article has some notes on this.

It should not be overused. The classic use case is for payments in banking scenarios. If the initial sign in / delegation used a password, the step up request might ask for a second factor, eg a PIN, but should not re-prompt for the password.

**CLIENTS AND ACCESS TOKENS**

It is awkward for a client to use multiple access tokens. If the original one had scope `read` then the stepped up one could use scope `read write payment` and completely replace the original one.

In this case you do not want the high privilege scope to hang around for long. This is yet another reason to use short lived access tokens (~ 15 minutes).

Interestingly also, different scopes the user has consented to can have different [times to live](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/#high-privilege-scopes-and-time-to-live), so that refreshed access tokens drop the payment scope.

**ADVANCED EXAMPLE**

Out of interest, here is an [interesting but complicated article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/consentors-in-financial-grade/) on payment workflows in Open Banking. A second OIDC redirect is used to get a payment scope after normal authentication but also to record consent in an audited manner. In a normal app this would be overkill however.

Comment: If we have OTP enabled, should we get the token prior to otp generation?or after otp validation? and in case its after, how to validate credentials in this case on login and how to generate token after otp validation without requiring the user to enter the credentials again and without having to save them under our db (since the identity server is only used to generate tokens)

Comment: Token issuing is always after authentication completes. On the first authentication, some kind of database record must be created that is used next time, in order for this to work logically.